# Backing up camel body

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to realize following route in Apache Camel:
Endpoint 1 receiving a message. The route initiates an request to Endpoint 2 (clear Body). The Transformer transforms Body of Endpoint 1 incomming Message by using the result of Endpoint 2.

[image]

I tried following:

```
from("direct:MessageEndpoint1")
  .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
  .to("http://localhost:9003/MessageEndpoint2")
  .process(new MessageTransformationProcessor())
  .to("direct:MessageEndpoint3");
```

The problem is, that body get overridden by message endpoint 2. I was thinking about backing up the message body into a property. But what ist best practise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Enterprise Integration Pattern you should be using here is `enricher`.

See: http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html

As you correctly identified, the body from Message Endpoint 1 is lost when you send the message `to` Message Endpoint 2.

Instead, you should try this pattern:

```
from("direct:MessageEndpoint1")
  .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
  .enrich("http://localhost:9003/MessageEndpoint2", new AggregationStrategy() {
    @Override
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
      // write an aggregation strategy that makes sense here...
    }
  })
  .process(new MessageTransformationProcessor())
  .to("direct:MessageEndpoint3");
```

Commonly, you can take the information you need in the response from `newExchange`, and set it as a property on `oldExchage`

```
oldExchange.setProperty("xyz", newExchange.getIn().getBody().get(...));
```